# Open cart bulk discount

Tags: plugins, opencart, discount

I want to add a flat discount on my opencart based site Help me how to add this discount? i tried to search extensions but i can't find a free extension to do that any body help

Bulk discount on all products.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply discounts under the discount tab here:

[image]

If you want to apply a discount to all products directly in the database, first make a copy of your shop and run an SQL query like this on the copy:

```
UPDATE `oc_product`
SET price = price * 0.9
```

Then once you've confirmed it works as expected, take a backup of your database and run the command on it.

Comment: I know this thing but i want to add discount on complete site and this process take a much time to edit single single product.